# How to split a string behind a particular marker

Tags: ruby, string

I would like to split a string into an array. I'm looking for the first word that isn't entirely capitalised, and want to split behind that.

```
"WORD WORD Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
```

or

```
"WORD Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
```

should result in

```
["WORD WORD", "Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."]
```

or

```
"WORD", "Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "behind"? Do you mean "before" or "after"?

Comment: Your second result is not a valid Ruby object.

Comment: Probably you are using the word "capitalized" wrong. Capitalized (in Ruby) means the first letter is up case and the rest are down case. You probably meant "the first word that isn't entirely upcased".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?=\p{Zs}(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+.*))\p{Zs}
```

**Explanation:**

I assume you have an input string that starts with ALLCAPS word(s) and the rest of the string is not. So,

- `(?=\p{Zs}(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+.*))` - A positive look-ahead checking if we have a space (`\p{Zs}`) followed by a Capital letter, then a non-capitalized letter, and then any characters but a newline, any number of repetitions
- `\p{Zs}` - We consume the space so as not to include it into the array element upon split.

Comment: Hi thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind explaining what it does?

Comment: I aded an explanation. Actually, you may adjust the regex to `(?=\p{Zs}(\p{Lu}+\p{Ll}+.*))\p{Zs}` to account for cases like `WORD CCccc cccc` (where the 2nd part starts with multiple upper-case letters).

Answer (score 2):

You could do matching instead of splitting.

```
> str = "WORD WORD Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
=> "WORD WORD Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
> str.scan(/^(.*?)\s*\b([A-Za-z]*[a-z][A-Za-z]*\b.*)/)
=> [["WORD WORD", "Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."]]
> "WORD Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc.....".scan(/^(.*?)\s*\b([A-Za-z]*[a-z][A-Za-z]*\b.*)/)
=> [["WORD", "Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."]]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uJ0cJ3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively without using Regex. (Not very elegant though):

```
str = "WORD WORD Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
arr = str.split
arr[arr.index{|b| b.upcase != b}..-1].join(" ")
# => "Cccc cccc cccc cccc CCCCC cccc....."
```